# 'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.' when calling aspx page from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-web-api

I want to call a aspx page from my method so I use `Redirect()` method as bellow:

```
pubic calsss mainController:ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void postReport()
    {
         Redirect("/WebForm1.aspx");
    } 
}
```

but when I use it it shows this Exception :
`'Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.'`

my `WebForm1.aspx` is an internal page.
can some one help me to solve this problem?

**Upadate:**

my web config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "withAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "noApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

My project structure :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can you replace your code like this:

```
return Redirect("~/Webform1.aspx");
```

Comment: Thanks @kadir ,I try it but my problem dosen't solved!!  may be this happen beacuse i use `apiController`.if you need more details ask me.

Comment: The reason might be the folder path of your aspx file. If you can give correct path I'm sure it will be resolved. For instance if it's under /webforms/forms/webform1 than it should be ~/webforms/forms/webform1.

Comment: Do you have another suggestion? Be careful i am using `ApiController`!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

If you wish to redirect to the folder that is one level higher than the current folder.

```
    Redirect("../WebForm1.aspx");
```

If you wish to redirect to the root directory use the tilde (~)

```
    Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
```

sample result: http:www.yoururl.co.uk/directory1/webform1.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Luke Hissey,I try it but my problem dosen't solved!!

Comment: try adding the word return before the redirect: return Redirect("../WebForm1.aspx"); This will give the method a return parameter